# Give nextline input to telnet

Tags: java, io, telnet

When i go to localhost and port via telnet i am able to connect but as soon as i give a single input it writes back. What i want is to wait for *nextline*  when i press enter and then give me the output of all the line.

```
public class NewIOServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocketChannel ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    ssc.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9000));
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    while (true) {
        SocketChannel sc = ssc.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected from: " + sc);
        try {
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);
            while (sc.read(buffer) != -1) {
                buffer.flip();
                for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++)
                    buffer.put(i, (byte) buffer.get(i));
                sc.write(buffer);
                buffer.clear();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Problems with the connections into the server - " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
}

}
```

Comment: It should work just fine. What operating system do you use? What telnet client? Seems like this is client related issue (I think client should not flush until input is confirmed).

Comment: i am using windows 7 64bit, i installed the telnet client via "Windows Features".

Comment: Maybe you could try another telnet client? For instance [putty](http://www.putty.org/).

Comment: This loop `for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++)
                    buffer.put(i, (byte) buffer.get(i));` does nothing. Remove it. And you need `buffer.compact()` after the `write()`. ANd you don't need a new `ByteBuffer` per read. Use the same one, initialized before the loop. There is no code here that attempts to accomplish your objective. If you were a real Telnet server you could put yourself into line mode, but you aren't. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see anything in your code that is actually waiting for a line to be completed before it is echoed back. Telnet clients, having traditionally been used for interactive shell sessions, usually send packets as soon as possible to decrease latency after a keystroke so of course your code will receive every keystroke pretty much immediately and write it back to the channel.